# How to Provide Global Types for External Module without @Types Definitions?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, refluxjs

Using TS 2.3.2 the [types format has changed](http://Error%20TS2503:%20Cannot%20find%20namespace%20'RefluxCore') so installing types requires *non-global* typings or NPM `@types` for global types.

This is all well and good except when global types are required and there are no NPM `@types` definitions - the error produced on compilation is:

> Error TS2503: Cannot find namespace '[MODULE-NAMESPACE]'

In my case the module is `RefluxCore` which doesn't have any NPM `@types` definitions.

For context the solution depends on an internally developed NPM package (which is the source of the above error) - this package depends on `RefluxCore`. Within the current solution of course I can just import `RefluxCore` - no problem - but the external package will need them to be provide globally.

**How can I provide types globally when there are no `@types` definitions available?**

*Just to reiterate the latest version of Typescript has a different approach to types which prevent external modules being installed globally by Typings.*